# Partial correlations with independent variable used as control?

Tags: partial-correlation

In my recent study I had one independent variable (IV, 2 levels) and a number of different DVs. The aim was to assess the relationship between teamwork (main response - continuous), presence (continuous), stress (3 continous variables - distress, engagement, worry) and immersion (the IV). This is really a sanity check for myself. I conducted partial correlations to ascertain the variance in teamwork accounted for by presence and stress without the shared variance of immersion (so the IV was used as a control in the partial correlation). Is the use of the IV "allowed" in partial correlations or is there a better way of achieving this? I am pretty new to stats so any help would be greatly appreciated. Added picture of table of correlations for reference. Thank you!
[image: Image of correlation table for reference]

Comment: By IV do you mean instrumental variable or independent variable?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant Independent Variable with two levels (high and low)